# Airflow InitDB issue

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, airflow, mysql-python

I am getting below error when i run airflow initdb after changing SQLALchemy details to connect to MySQL in airflow.cfg file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/airflow", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import conf
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 405, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 294, in configure_orm
    engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, connect_args=connect_args, **engine_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please help on this issue

Comment: Looks like you're missing the required libraries. Have you tried installing the appropriate mysql dependencies?

Comment: Yes. I have installed all the required libraries and mysql is up and running. But still am getting this error.

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you running?

Comment: I am using 1.10.12 airflow version. I have reinstalled mysql-python libraries and now able to connect to mysql db from airflow. Thanks all for your help.